# Direction of current detected by ammeter for ions

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, batteries, electrochemistry

[image]

if the pipe contains Na+ and Cl- ions, will the ammeter have the reading as $enAV_{Na}$+$enAV_{Cl}$
or $enAV_{Na}$-$enAV_{Cl}$ (as the ions move in opposite directions?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Superposition tells you that it is an addition.
A flow of negative charges in a given direction is equivalent to a flow of positive charges in the opposite direction.